# twython can't get data for $EURUSD

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twython

I am using *twython* to get 7 day data from twitter.

It works for all tags except `$EURUSD`

It raises `StopIteration` before getting 7 day data.

Comment: Do you mean hashtag?

Comment: no. symbol $EURUSD

Comment: What's that? Could please give an example or share the documentation?

Comment: its for forex symbols

Comment: `$EURUSD` or `#EURUSD`?